# Proving $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)+g(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)+\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=M$. I was attempting to prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)+g(x)=L+M$.

The following is my attempt at a proof.

Proof: We have to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all those values of $x$ for which $|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have that $|f(x)+g(x)-(L+M)|<\varepsilon$.

Because $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=M$, we know that $|f(x)-L|<\frac\varepsilon 2$ and $|g(x)-M|<\frac \varepsilon 2$ for all values of $x$ for which $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Adding the two inequalities we get that $|f(x)-L|+|g(x)-M|<\varepsilon $. Using the triangle inequality we get that $|f(x)+g(x)-(L+M)|< \varepsilon$ for all those values of $x$ for which $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

In other words, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)+g(x)=L+M$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: @Andreas My bad, I meant $|f(x)-L|$ and $|g(x)-M|$. I will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a bit more careful, as the $\delta$'s for the two limits might not be the same. Indeed if $\delta_1$ is the one for $f$, and $\delta_2$ is the one for $g$, then set $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and your argument works.

Comment: Forgot about that. Thanks for the answer!